# Calculate distance using two different datums at the same time

Tags: android, sql-server, linux

Is it possible to measure the distance between two points using different datums?

E.g. Lat/Long of London obtained using the OSGB36 grid and say Paris Lat/ long obtained from GPS (WGS84)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert one of the datums to the other's type to be able to carry out the calculation. See [this handy article](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html). There's also some JavaScript code included that should be fairly simple to port to .NET or Java (or use as is.)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Your answer has cleared up a few misconceptions I had over datums.